# Validate condition using regex with variables

Tags: python, regex

I have a Python program which takes in user input like below:

```
python3 script.py in.csv ‘Length>4.5;Height<1'
```

`in.csv` is the input data on which certain conditions are to be applied. In the above example, Length and Height are variables from input data. Any number of conditions are possible. In the above example, there are 2 conditions on 2 different variables. In reality it could be more number of variables.
My variable list is (all are numeric variables):

```
var_list = ['Length' , 'Height', 'Weight', 'Version', 'ID']
```

I would like to:

1. Validate the condition is a valid logical expression.
2. Filter the data using the condition.

For this purpose, I would like to build a regex to solve part 1 and I think part 2 will follow if I am able to crack part 1. But I'm unable to build the regex and match against the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, i'd split the argument by ';', to get a list of the comparisons you inputted.
2. The appropriate regex i see would be "((\w+)([><=])(.+))" which should match both
3. i'd map the regex on to the list we got from step 1, to get the matches
4. and then you can use the group() to get each part of the matches.

```py
import re

a = "Length>4.5;Height<1".split(';')
r = re.compile(r'(\w+)(>=|<=|[><=])([0-9]+\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)')
res = list(map(r.match, a))
print(res[0].group(0)) # 'Length>4.5'
print(res[0].group(1)) # 'Length'
print(res[0].group(2)) # '>'
print(res[0].group(3)) # '4.5'

# res[1] has 'Height<1'
```